# How to choose port in socket programming?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm currently learning socket programming in python, and I'm puzzled on how to select the ports for my servers to listen to. I'm aware that I can't choose some specific range (up to 3000 or something?), so I selected the ports way beyond that number (7777 to be precise).

In my scenario, I would like to test my program using different number of servers (multiples of 12 up to 96). So far I'm testing my program with 12 server codes, assigning the host to `localhost`, and port numbers from `7777` to `7788`.

Sometimes when I run my program, python intepreter says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/myUserName/sockettutorial/sockettest4/ppc1/dir12/nwserver12.py", line 9, in <module>
    s.bind((host,port))
  File "<string>", line 1, in bind
socket.error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

despite I've killed all the relevant processes that may still listen to the said ports (using `netstat -plan` to check for the PIDs of those processes).

I have included this part in my server codes:

```
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
```

My problem here is that despite the error, the program works as expected, and sometimes when I run my program, I didn't get this error at all and sometimes I did. However, the error itself is kinda annoying and if I want to get rid of it, is there any way to let the machine/host assign the available ports for the servers, or do I have to manually assign them?

Thank you for all the answers!

Comment: When you list all socket listeners (e.g. via `netstat -a|grep "LISTEN"`) on your system it does even appear in a mode called `TIME_WAIT`?

Comment: I haven't looked into the details. Will try and observe today and will let you know.

Answer (score 9):

When you bind a server to a port to listen for incoming connections, you need to specify the port. A lot of services have a "standard" port which they run on by default, e.g. HTTP: 80, HTTPS: 443, SSH: 22. This is so clients know which port to send data to when they connect (if something is on a random port, the client can't connect).

If you want to have the OS pick a port for you when you bind, you can bind to port zero. You can then find out what port you were assigned by using `getsockname`. Example:

```
>>> s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
>>> s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 0))
>>> s.getsockname()
('127.0.0.1', 42171)
```

Port numbers are a short int (16 bits), so their range is 0-65535. Ports below 1000 are usually reserved for "known" services, like those mentioned above, and services serving on them usually need to be run as root.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, so maybe it's possible to write a python script to generate server codes targeting those ports and then at the same time connect the client code to those. I'll give it a try! Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: `Port 0` is used for listeners to let the OS pick up a non-assigned port and it always works (unless there is really no port available which is nearly impossible). After the listener is bound to a specific port you can read out which port was picked by the OS. Discovery-Services can register your service then in the local network so every client is aware of the port number.

Comment: @HelloWorld Thanks for the info. I've updated my answer to suggest using port 0.

Comment: There's something I don't understand. Suppose I bind my server sockets to port 0, how would I have to code the client side, i.e. how do I know which port do I need to connect to a specific server? (I need this because each server will handle a different task and I need specificity and obtain a correct order of the data from the servers)

Comment: @KhunWasut Often if you are spawning a bunch of servers on different ports you will have some kind of master server which is on a known port, and the spawned processes will report their IP/Port to the master, and get information about each other's port numbers from the master. Alternatively, if the number of servers being spawned is fixed, you really could just pick fixed port numbers for them. If you want to spawn servers dynamically you may need a master on a fixed port to coordinate.

Comment: @zstewart Thank you for the suggestion. That should work in my situation.